how do i set ‘random_state’ correctly so that my results are always the same?
If I have for example this snippet of code:
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=knn,
    n_jobs=-1)

Do I have to set it like this:
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(random_state=42)

grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=knn,
    n_jobs=-1
)

Or do I have to set it like this?
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(random_state=42)

grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=knn,
    random_state=42,
    n_jobs=-1
)

what is the correct why? And what if I use randomisedsearch instead of gridsearch?

In this case, setting the random_state depends on the specific algorithm you’re using, rather than on the GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV class.
For KNeighborsClassifier, adding random_state is actually unnecessary because this classifier is a deterministic algorithm, meaning it doesn’t rely on randomness to make predictions. Therefore, it won’t be affected by a random_state parameter. As a result:

For KNeighborsClassifier: You don’t need to set random_state at all in either the classifier or in the GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV.

For Randomized Algorithms: If you’re using an algorithm that involves randomness, like a decision tree or a random forest, you can set the random_state in the estimator (like RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)). You don’t need to set random_state in GridSearchCV, as it only influences the cross-validation process, which is deterministic.


In summary:

For KNeighborsClassifier: No random_state is needed.
For Randomized algorithms: Set random_state in the estimator, not in GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV.
For RandomizedSearchCV: You might set random_state there if the search itself is randomized and you want reproducibility.


Is logistic regression, svm, decisiontree, adaboost and xgboost a randomized algoithm?



Logistic Regression: This is typically a deterministic algorithm,


Support Vector Machine: SVM itself is deterministic, if you're using it with stochastic solvers (like in SGDClassifier), randomness can play a role, and you might want to set random_state in those cases.


Decision Tree: Decision trees can involve randomness when the max_features parameter is set.


AdaBoost:  is deterministic, but its underlying base estimator can be randomized if it’s not fully grown


XGBoost: XGBoost also involves randomness in subsampling.



As described above, for sklearn you can set the random_state parameter within the model for the relevant models.
The GridSearchCV also uses some randomization in the cross validation, so best to fix the seed in the model and in the grid search as well:
grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
    cv=KFold(3, random_state=42),
    n_jobs=-1

)

or
grid_search_dt = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42),
        cv=KFold(3, random_state=42),
        n_jobs=-1)

Beside that, you might want to set the seed for other packages as well if you use them for processing the data:
import numpy as np
import random 

def set_random_seed(random_seed=42):
    """
    Set seed for hte random, numpy.random
    : param random_seed (int) : initial value for the random seed generators.
    """
    random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    #torch.manual_seed(random_seed)


set_random_seed()

And also in you train-test split:
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)


Thank you is it also possible to make:
grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(
estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
cv=KFold(3),
random_state=42,
n_jobs=-1
)
instead of the random state directly in cv?
